# Oracle - xmlindex slows down the insert operation

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

Scenario - I have created XMLINDEX on a table to speed up my Select query.

Now, Select query becomes very fast.
However, Insert operation to the table becomes very slow.

I cant make the index unusable at the time of data loading because at the same time Select query could run and need xmlindex.

I tried no_index and few xmlindex hints but every time it was slow. If I make the xmlindex unusable then of course, my insert completes in <1 secs.

Is there any way to load the data by keeping xmlindex? Like any hint?

Sample insert script:

```
insert into table_xml -- this table has xmlindex, here i dont want to use xmlindex

select * from some_other_table;
-----------------------------------------------
select * from table_xml, xmltable (...); -- here xmlindex is giving great performance
```

Comment: How the xmlindex looks like? Your question is too broad?

Comment: Is it possible that you could set the index to be deferred ? That way you could define a synchronisation 'schedule'. Obviously there would be a trade-off in that the SELECTs against the data added since the last SYNC will be slow. It depends on your application, I guess. The Oracle documentation is here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb_indexing.htm#CHDBCBHD

Comment: The problem is not that your insert is **"using"** the index, it is that it is necessarily **maintaining** the index so that it is usable by select statements.  If the selects need the index to be up to date then you have no choice but to take the hit on the inserts.  Of course, you could perhaps do your data loading "out of hours" when you can make the index unusable during the load.

Comment: ASYNC (SYNC MANUAL) parameter will solve the issue.